# How to change background color of object choice field in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to change background color of selected item in object choice Field in blackberry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this sample code:

```java
public class SamplePopupScreen extends PopupScreen
{
    BitmapField bitmapField[];
    Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("box-s6A.png");

    public SamplePopupScreen()
    {
        super(new VerticalFieldManager(),PopupScreen.DEFAULT_CLOSE);
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI()
    {
        bitmapField=new BitmapField[3];
        add(new LabelField("Popup Screen",Field.FIELD_HCENTER));

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            VerticalFieldManager vr=new VerticalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER|VERTICAL_SCROLL|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

            bitmapField[i]=new BitmapField(null,Field.FOCUSABLE|Field.FIELD_HCENTER)
            {
                protected void paint(Graphics g)
                {
                    g.clear();
                    g.drawText("LabelNunber", 0, 0);
                    if(isFocus())
                    {
                        g.drawBitmap(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap, 0, 0);
                        g.drawText("LabelNunber",0,0);
                    }
                }
                protected void layout(int width, int height)
                {
                    super.layout(250, 50);
                    setExtent(250, 50);
                }
            };
            vr.add(bitmapField[i]);
            add(vr);
        }
    }
}
```

and I am getting like this:

[image: Set Image on selected list]

Comment: This is a popupscreen... not an ObjectChoiceField.

Comment: @Jonathan Fisher I and the question asking person, know it is a popup screen. You should have to convert according to your requirement. Nobody can give the full code.

Answer (score 2):

Read the BlackBerry API documents for [Field.setBackground(Background background)](http://file:///G:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/Research%20In%20Motion/BlackBerry%20JDE%207.1.0/docs/api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setBackground%28net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.Background%29), [Field.setBackground(int visual, Background background)](http://file:///G:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/Research%20In%20Motion/BlackBerry%20JDE%207.1.0/docs/api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setBackground%28int,%20net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.Background%29) and [Background](http://file:///G:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/Research%20In%20Motion/BlackBerry%20JDE%207.1.0/docs/api/net/rim/device/api/ui/decor/Background.html).